# Using KV langaue of Kivy to compute points on a canvas

Tags: layout, kivy

I want to draw a few triangles in a canvas, which will resize as I resize the window. The code use is as follow

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import  Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

    Builder.load_string("""

    <ScreenUI>:
        radius: 0.9 * min(self.center_x, self.center_y)
        tside: 2 * (min(self.center_x, self.center_y) - self.radius / 1.4)
        r_width: self.center_x + self.radius
        r_x: self.center_x - self.radius

        canvas:
            Triangle:
                points: root.r_x, 0, root.tside, 0, 0, root.tside
            Triangle:
                points: root.r_width, 0, root.r_x - root.tside, 0, root.r_width, root.tside
    """)

    class ScreenUI(BoxLayout):
        pass

    class WidgetApp(App): 

        def build(self):
            app = ScreenUI()
            return app

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        WidgetApp().run()
```

The errors I get are:

```
kivy.lang.BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 13:
...
  11:            points: root.r_x, 0, root.tside, 0, 0, root.tside
  12:        Triangle:
>>13:            points: root.r_width, 0, root.r_x - root.tside, 0, root.r_width,   root.tside
...
BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 13:
...
  11:            points: root.r_x, 0, root.tside, 0, 0, root.tside
  12:        Triangle:
>>13:            points: root.r_width, 0, root.r_x - root.tside, 0, root.r_width, root.tside
 ...
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

How can I use just the KV language to compute al the corners of the triangles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the properties to the `ScreenUI` Python class:

```
class ScreenUI(BoxLayout):
    radius = NumericProperty(0)
    tside = NumericProperty(0)
    r_width = NumericProperty(0)
    r_x = NumericProperty(0)
```

Don't forget to import the `NumericProperty`:

```
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
```